# Client registration data of AdapterSecurityContext is null while testing the API using POSTMAN

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, postman, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have written a server side REST API which requires client registartion data to perform some operation. I have used AdapterSecurityContext and I am fetching the client registration data using getClientRegistrationData method of AdapterSecurityContext. I need to test the API before giving the endpoint to mobile APP developers  so I am trying to check the API suing POSTMAN.

The problem is when I try to hit the same API from POSTMAN for testing the response I get nullpointer exception because getClientRegistrationData is null. I am begginer in MFP so I just needed to know is it possible to pass client registration data through POSTMAN or it can only be obtained when adapter is connected to mobile client.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve client registration data only when you invoke adapter endpoints using mobile/web clients.

This doesn't work with confidential clients.